# How to convert UTF-16 to and from ASCII

Tags: assembly, unicode, ascii, mips, utf-16

I'm writing a subroutine in MIPS assembly language to convert ASCII into UTF-16 and vice versa. However, I could not find any trick how to convert it.

Comment: Are you converting to UTF-16? UTF-8?

Comment: Your question title says "UTF-16 to ASCII" but your question says "ASCII to UTF-16" -- which one is correct?

Comment: i need both. I wrote vice versa :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pseudocode, assuming that your bytes are octets and that no zero termination is required:

### Conversion from ASCII to UTF-16

1. Given an ASCII input string of length *n* (in bytes) stored sequentially in memory at address *p*.
2. Allocate 2 × *n* bytes of memory; let the start address of that memory be *q*.
3. While *n* is larger than zero:

   1. Check whether the byte at *p* is a valid ASCII character. If you don't use checksumming, the most significant bit has to be zero, otherwise it has to be the correct checksum. Issue an error if the byte is not valid.
   2. Zero-extend the byte at *p* to the 16-bit word at *q*. How this is done depends on the instruction set; e.g., x86 has `MOVZX`. You may also pay attention to the correct endianness.
   3. Increment *p* by 1.
   4. Increment *q* by 2.
   5. Decrement *n* by 1.

### Lossless conversion from UTF-16 to ASCII

1. Given an UTF-16 input string of length *n* (in code units) stored sequentially in memory at address *p*.
2. Allocate *n* bytes of memory; let the start address of that memory be *q*.
3. While *n* is larger than zero:

   1. Check whether the 16-bit word at *p* represents a valid ASCII character. The nine most significant bits have to be zero, otherwise the character is not representable in ASCII. Issue an error if the word is not valid.
   2. Move the least significant byte of the 16-bit word at *p* to the byte at *q*.
   3. If required, add a checksum to the byte at *q*.
   4. Increment *p* by 2.
   5. Increment *q* by 1.
   6. Decrement *n* by 1.

Comment: MIPS has `lhu $t0, ($t1)` to Load 16-bit Halfword (with zero extension) or `lh` for the same with sign-extension, into a full register.  If you use sign-extension, that will replicate the top bit of the byte up to the top of the full register, where you can `bltz` to branch on it being negative (sign-bit set).  Or `blez` to do that as part of the same branch that detects a terminating 0, if you're using C strings.

Answer (score 3):

The term ASCII is not very specific.

ISO-646 is a subset of Unicode UTF-16. So '7-bit' ASCII numbers *are already* Unicode (i.e. you just drop them into the bottom of a 16 bit value), and, for the other direction, all you have to do is take the low 8 bits from Unicode to get the ASCII if this is what you mean.

If you need, on the other hand, ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1), you'll need a conversion table. There is no formula that can be translated into simple instructions in assembly language.

Comment: should I take the low 16 bits or 7 bits from Unicde?

Comment: well, what about ASCII to UTF-16 ?

Comment: Every ASCII char translates to a UTF-16 char with the high byte as 0.

Comment: You don't need a conversion table for ISO-8859-1 as well because the bottom 256 Unicode characters are exactly identical to the ISO-8859-1 character set. Therefore the conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-16 is as simple as in the case of ASCII: take the bytes, and insert a null byte after each of them.

Comment: No. Not true. Only ISO-646 is identical, not latin-1.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only have UCS2 (only 16-bit codepoints) you can convert directly to ASCII by doing a `short <-> char`-conversion only converting numbers smaller than 128.

Comment: no this is not what i'm looking for. I need to convert in assembly level.

Comment: Well, you should know how to copy bytes on your platform :) And if it's Big or Little Endian. If it's Big Endian you need to copy the second byte, if it's Little Endian you need to copy the first one.

Comment: This has not so much to do with UCS-2. You can only losslessly convert the bottom 128 bit characters from Unicode to ASCII, all of which are inside the BMP.

Comment: Well, if you want to convert UTF-16 you have to convert codepoints outside of the BMP, which are 32-bit long, differently, which is why my solution is only valid for UCS-2.

Comment: @filmor: Or portably to MIPS in either big-endian or little-endian mode, `lhu $t0, ($t1)` (Load Halfword, zero-extending into a register) / `sb $t0, ($t2)` (Store Byte) / increment pointers.  That requires your UTF-16 data is aligned (starting on an even address), but lets the CPU take care of getting the integer value of a 16-bit load, instead of needing `lbu $t0 1($t1)` (big-endian) or `0($t1)` (little-endian) to manually load the least-significant byte.